# ASP.Net MVC: Dropdown which is used in almost all pages

Tags: user-controls, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a user dropdown which comes in most of add/edit pages which comes from database. Right now in all actions, I am getting the users in a viewbag and creating dropdown in the view. Is this the right way? Can someone help me in a way I can call one usercontrol and the dropdown is created with proper name and value. Or can someone suggest what is the right method.

Comment: Why dont you just create a simple model and call that everywhere its needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do, is create a base ViewModel class, which contains the values for the dropdown. Than let all other ViewModels inherit from the base class.

Than create an ActionFilter that fills the DropdownMenu Items list. The _Layout view should have the dropdown in it.

[Here is a working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670643/adding-value-to-base-class-property-in-actionfilter)

Answer (score 0):

i am using the pretty basic style ... i had a actionresult which returns the dropdown item description and item id as json... and i use the same  in all the views where it is needed ...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/contoller/ActionName")", null, function (records) {
                    for (i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                        $('#selection_code').append($('<option></option>').text(records[i].Product_Description).attr('ID', records[i].Product_Type_ID));
                    }
                });
});
```

selection_code is the id of my dropdown

.. this can be also done by adding a partial view and appending it to a div in the view so that when ever the partial view is used we can get the dropdown!!!